# Playwright on Azure Functions Python based

Tags: docker, azure-functions, cloud, playwright-python

I am trying to scrape a website using playwright and host it on Azure Functions. However, playwright requires Chrome drivers which I can't seem to install into Azure Functions.

Unsure how to do this step in a pipeline:

```
pip install playwright
playwright install
```

Previously, I tried to do it in an azure pipeline:

```
  - script: |
    python -m venv ./azfunc/.python_packages
    source ./azfunc/.python_packages/bin/activate
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip keyring artifacts-keyring
    pip install -r ./azfunc/requirements.txt
    python -m playwright install
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'
```

However, I get a `webkit" browser was not found.Please complete Playwright installation via running"python -m playwright install`
It seems like the Azure Function is not finding where it was installed. Any suggestions? Would using Docker be a good tactic?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like azure functions support headless chromium with consumption based app service plan.

Here is the blog to know more about the [running headless chromium in azure functions with playwright](https://dev.to/azure/running-headless-chromium-in-azure-functions-with-puppeteer-and-playwright-2fgk?utm_source=dormosheio&utm_campaign=dormosheio)

over this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-dotnet/issues/1076) ,it was suggested to use the [azure functions on docker container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-python)

please file a  [support ticket](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) and MS Q&A [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I would be looking to use it in Python which there doesn't seem to a be a solution for. Either way, I created my own custom docker image and installed all the necessary dependencies in there.